# how to implement like operator in prepared statement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g, prepared-statement

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from REGISTER inner join ORGAN on REGISTER.PATIENTID=ORGAN.PATIENTID where ORGAN.ORGAN LIKE ?");          
ps.setString(1,"'%"+o.getOrgan()+"%'");
```

I executed the query in SQL Developer which works fine, but in DAO class it is not returning any result set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
ps.setString(1, "%" + o.getOrgan() + "%");
```

Note the absence of quotes.

Comment: thanks a lot..it is working @JB Nizet